# After Linux OS upgrade audio is 20% quieter - how to get back to previous level?

Tags: linux, audio, opensuse, alsa, pulse-audio

I just upgraded my OpenSUSE OS and the volume output is not as high as before. I would say it's 20% quieter compared to before the upgrade.

I'm guessing its a matter of selecting the right option for the `snd-hda-intel` driver.

Here is the output of aplay

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The system is using pulseaudio and is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with kernel  5.14.6-1.

How can restore the previous audio levels?

Comment: After similar issues with Ubuntu, I installed an audio mixer to increase volume. *Pulse Audio Equalizer* and *Alsamixer* are a couple of chioces. See https://software.opensuse.org/package/pulseaudio-equalizer and https://pkgs.org/download/gnome-alsamixer. Admittedly, a kluge, but it was the easiest fix for me.

Comment: Thanks I'll try these mixers.